# How to send value from one fragment to another fragment from Recyclerview Adapter. Then close the first fragment and open the new Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment

I need to send a value when i click on a row in recyclerview to another fragment (I thin on OnBind in the adapter). Then i need to close the fragment that contain the recyclerview and open the receiver fragment. I read somewhere that we can use bundle, but I am pretty new to android programming so I am confused.

**This is the Fragment that contain RecyclerView**

```
public class PasienFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private OnPasienFragmentInteractionListener mPasienListener;

    public PasienFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    int countICU=0;
    int countINAP=0;
    int countUMUM=0;
    int countBPJS=0;

    RequestQueue queue;
    String jenisAsuransi,jenisKamar;
    String id="C0E0607E";
    ImageView ivTotal,ivIcu,ivInap,ivBpjs,ivUmum;
    TextView tvTOTAL,tvICU,tvINAP,tvBPJS,tvUMUM;

    public static final String URL_JUMLAH = "http:"; 

    public static PasienFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PasienFragment fragment = new PasienFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pasien, container, false);
        ivTotal = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivTotal);
        ivIcu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivICU);
        ivBpjs = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivBPJS);
        ivInap = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivINAP);
        ivUmum = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivUMUM);

        tvTOTAL = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
        tvICU = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvICU);
        tvBPJS = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvBPJS);
        tvINAP = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvINAP);
        tvUMUM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvUMUM);

        ivTotal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mPasienListener.onPasienFragmentInteraction("Daftar Pasien");
            }
        });

        ivIcu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mPasienListener.onPasienFragmentInteraction("Daftar Pasien ICU");
            }
        });

        ivBpjs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mPasienListener.onPasienFragmentInteraction("Daftar Pasien BPJS");
            }
        });

        ivInap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mPasienListener.onPasienFragmentInteraction("Daftar Pasien INAP");
            }
        });

        ivUmum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mPasienListener.onPasienFragmentInteraction("Daftar Pasien UMUM");
            }
        });

        String url1 = URL_JUMLAH+id;
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(url1, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        JSONArray users = null;
                        try {
                            users = response.getJSONArray("result1");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = users.getJSONObject(i);
                                jenisAsuransi = (String) obj.get("Jenis_Asuransi");
                                jenisKamar = (String) obj.get("Jenis_Kamar");
                                if(jenisAsuransi.equals("BPJS")){
                                    countBPJS++;
                                }
                                if(jenisAsuransi.equals("UMUM")){
                                    countUMUM++;
                                }
                                if(jenisKamar.equals("INAP")){
                                    countINAP++;
                                }
                                if(jenisKamar.equals("ICU")){
                                    countICU++;
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        tvTOTAL.setText(String.valueOf(users.length()));
                        tvBPJS.setText(String.valueOf(countBPJS));
                        tvUMUM.setText(String.valueOf(countUMUM));
                        tvINAP.setText(String.valueOf(countINAP));
                        tvICU.setText(String.valueOf(countICU));
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Terjadi Kendala Koneksi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }
        });
        queue.add(req);

        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(String sentence) {
        if (mPasienListener != null) {
            mPasienListener.onPasienFragmentInteraction(sentence);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnPasienFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mPasienListener = (OnPasienFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mPasienListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnPasienFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onPasienFragmentInteraction(String sentence);
    }
}
```

**This is the RecyclerView adapter**

```
public class ListPasienAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListPasienAdapter.PasienViewHolder> {

    private List<Pasien> pasienList;
    public int count = 0;
    public ListPasienAdapter(List<Pasien> pasienList) {
        this.pasienList = pasienList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PasienViewHolder pasienViewHolder, int i) {

        final Pasien pi = pasienList.get(i);
        pasienViewHolder.tvTanggal.setText(pi.Tgl_Masuk);
        pasienViewHolder.tvNama.setText(pi.Nama_Pasien + "/" + pi.Gender);
        pasienViewHolder.tvKamar.setText(pi.No_Kamar);

        if (pi.Perawatan.toString().equals("Merah")) {
            pasienViewHolder.ivRambu.setImageResource(R.drawable.merah);
        } else if (pi.Perawatan.toString().equals("Kuning")) {
            pasienViewHolder.ivRambu.setImageResource(R.drawable.kuning);
        } else if (pi.Perawatan.toString().equals("Hijau")) {
            pasienViewHolder.ivRambu.setImageResource(R.drawable.hijau);
        }

        pasienViewHolder.ivRambu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public ListPasienAdapter.PasienViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_pasien, viewGroup, false);
        return new ListPasienAdapter.PasienViewHolder(itemView);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pasienList.size();
    }

    public static class PasienViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView tvTanggal;
        protected TextView tvNama;
        protected TextView tvKamar;
        protected TextView tvGender;
        protected ImageView ivRambu;
        protected ImageView ivDown;
        protected ImageView btnIngat;
        protected ImageView btnTerkirim;
        protected TextView tvPeringatan;
        protected LinearLayout btnDetail;

        public PasienViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tvTanggal = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTanggal);
            tvNama = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNama);
            tvKamar = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvKamar);
            ivRambu = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivRambu);
            ivDown = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivDown);
            //btnIngat = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.btnIngat);
            //btnTerkirim = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.btnTerkirim);
            btnDetail = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.btnDetail);
            //tvPeringatan = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPeringatan);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the receiver Fragment**

```
public class ListAktivitas extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public ListAktivitas() {
        // Required empty publtic constructor
    }

    public static final String URL_LIST_Aktivitas = "http";
    public static final String URL_Pasien = "http://";
    String id="3";
    RequestQueue queue;
    List<Aktivitas> resultAktivitas = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Pasien> resultPasien = new ArrayList<>();
    Aktivitas a = new Aktivitas();
    ListAktivitasAdapter laa;

    RecyclerView cardListAktivitas;

    Integer Urut;
    String Nama_Prosedur;
    String Id_Prosedur;
    String Id_Aktivitas;
    String Status;
    String Nama_Pasien, No_Kamar, Gender;
    Context context;

    TextView tvNamaPasien,tvKamar;


    public static ListAktivitas newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ListAktivitas fragment = new ListAktivitas();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        context = getActivity();
       }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_aktivitas, container, false);

        cardListAktivitas = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardListAktivitas);
        cardListAktivitas.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        cardListAktivitas.setLayoutManager(llm);

        tvNamaPasien = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNamaPasien);
        tvKamar = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvKamar);

        String url2 = URL_Pasien+id;
        JsonObjectRequest req2 = new JsonObjectRequest(url2, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        JSONArray users = null;
                        try {
                            users = response.getJSONArray("result1");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = users.getJSONObject(0);
                                Nama_Pasien = (String) obj.get("Nama_Pasien");
                                No_Kamar = (String) obj.get("No_Kamar");
                                if(obj.get("Gender").toString().equals("Laki-laki")){
                                    Gender = "L";
                                }else if (obj.get("Gender").toString().equals("Perempuan")){
                                    Gender = "P";
                                }
                                resultPasien.add(new Pasien(Nama_Pasien, No_Kamar,Gender));

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        tvNamaPasien.setText(Nama_Pasien+"/"+Gender);
                        tvKamar.setText("kamar:"+No_Kamar);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Terjadi Kendala Koneksi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }
        });
        queue.add(req2);

        String url1 = URL_LIST_Aktivitas+id;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), url1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(url1, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        JSONArray users = null;
                        try {
                            users = response.getJSONArray("result1");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(users.length()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = users.getJSONObject(i);
                                Urut = (Integer) obj.get("Urut");
                                Nama_Prosedur= (String) obj.get("Nama_Prosedur");
                                Id_Prosedur = (String) obj.get("Id_Prosedur");
                                Id_Aktivitas = String.valueOf(obj.getInt(Id_Aktivitas));
                                Status = (String) obj.get("Status");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(context,Nama_Prosedur, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            resultAktivitas.add(new Aktivitas(Urut, Nama_Prosedur, Id_Prosedur, Id_Aktivitas, Status));
                            laa = new ListAktivitasAdapter(resultAktivitas);
                            cardListAktivitas.setAdapter(laa);
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Terjadi Kendala Koneksi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }
        });
        queue.add(req);

        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

*/
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

**This is the activity that contain the 2 fragment**

```
public class PasienActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,PasienFragment.OnPasienFragmentInteractionListener {


    PasienFragment pasienFragment;
    ListPasienFragment listPasienFragment;
    ListAktivitas listAktivitasFragment;

    RequestQueue queue;

    String Nama_Dokter,Nama_RS;

    public static final String URL_LIST = "http:";
    String id="vvvv";

    View navHeaderView;
    TextView tvNavDokter, tvNavRS;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pasien);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        listPasienFragment = new ListPasienFragment();
        listPasienFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.listPasienContainer, listPasienFragment).commit();


        pasienFragment = new PasienFragment();
        pasienFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.pasienFragmentContainer,pasienFragment).commit();


        listAktivitasFragment = new ListAktivitas();
        listAktivitasFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.listAktivitasContainer, listAktivitasFragment).commit();


        View navHeaderView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        tvNavDokter = (TextView) navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.tvNavDokter);
        tvNavRS = (TextView) navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.tvNavRS);

        String url1 = URL_LIST+id;
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(url1, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        JSONArray users = null;
                        try {
                            users = response.getJSONArray("result1");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = users.getJSONObject(0);
                                Nama_Dokter = (String) obj.get("Nama_Dokter");
                                Nama_RS = (String) obj.get("Rumah_Sakit");

                                tvNavDokter.setText(Nama_Dokter);
                                tvNavRS.setText(Nama_RS);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Terjadi Kendala Koneksi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }
        });
        queue.add(req);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pasien, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        /*
        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }
        */


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPasienFragmentInteraction(String sentence) {
        if(listPasienFragment!=null)
            listPasienFragment.updateSentence(sentence);
    }

}
```

Comment: [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can send data using bundle to fragment.
EG. `Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putString("key", "value");

NewFragment newFragment = new NewFragment ();
newFragment.setArguments(eventDetailsData);`

Then load fragment.

To kill/remove current fragment execute below code
getActivity().onBackPressed();